# IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm: how to make fetch keyword (XMLHttpRequest analogue) to be recognized?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

It seems WebStorm 2016.3.1 knows nothing about [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). It marks `fetch`
keyword as an error in JavaScript. As a workaround I add `/* global fetch */` comment at the top of each JavaScript file where I use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Is there a better way (I didn't find anything useful in Download Library (Definitely Typed) dialog)?

Comment: Just a note that WebStorm 2019.2.3 has this. I haven't checked to see in what version between 2016.3 and 2019.2.3 it was added.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that by adding whatwg-fetch to my `package.json` file via NPM/Yarn in my project directory, it adds whatwg-fetch's polyfill to the project's node_modules directory which IntelliJ IDEA/WebStorm/* is generally configured to read from. This adds support for the Fetch API to JetBrains's auto-completion engine and seems to work like a charm.

Here's an example:

```
C:\Project> npm install whatwg-fetch
```

After performing this, you should be able to see the module installed as follows:

```
C:\Project> dir /w node_modules\whatwg-fetch\
 Directory of C:\Project\node_modules\whatwg-fetch

[.]            [..]           fetch.js       LICENSE        package.json   README.md
               4 File(s)         22,824 bytes
               2 Dir(s)
```

Here's the results in IntelliJ IDEA, when `node_modules` is configured as a library directory with the whatwg-fetch polyfill installed:

[image: Screenshot of proper recognition]